# How to switch citation style from author-year to author-number using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

Have been using `biblatex` apa-style of author-year citation for a while, now i want to change the style to author-number style:

For example: as with `\cite{Loh:1992}`

Before:

```
 ...
 Loh (1992)
 ...
```

References:

```
Loh, N. C. (1992). High-resolution micromachined interferometric accelerometer (Master’s thesis,Massachusetts Institute of Technology, Cambridge, Mass.)
```

How to achieve Author [num] style like:

```
 ...
 Loh [1] ...
 ...
```

References:

```
[1] Loh, N. C. (1992). High-resolution micromachined interferometric accelerometer (Master’s thesis,Massachusetts Institute of Technology, Cambridge, Mass.)
```

I have searched the forum and found most of the solution are based to `bibtex` and they can't be applied to `biblatex`.

So how to figure this out.

PS: the`biblatex` setting is attached:

```
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    refsection=chapter,
    uniquename=true,
    uniquelist=false,
    maxcitenames=2, 
    natbib=true ]{biblatex} 
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\LetLtxMacro{\cite}{\citet}  % year in ()

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  bibliography = {References}  }
```

Comment: What is wrong with, say, `style=numeric`? Are you wanting APA formatting for the bibliography, but with numeric citation labels?

Comment: @PaulStanley, yes, I want the Apa-style numeric citation. Another question, the order of Literatures in the `Reference list` are sorted by author's surname, other than citing order in text. Is this default for numeric citation?

Comment: Yes. Sorting by citing order may be achieved with the `sorting=none` package option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to switch to a `numeric` style -- add `style=numeric` to the `biblatex` package options or (as `numeric` is the default style) simply omit other style specifications.

With `numeric`, the standard `\cite` command will produce *only* a number (by default within square brackets). For citations in the flow of the text that require the author name plus the number of the cited work use `\textcite`.

The bibliography will be sorted alphabetically by author name. Should you want sorting by citing order, add the `sorting=none` package option.

Comment: \textcite works fine.  Is there \textcitep command?

Comment: @KOF What should `\textcitep` do?

Comment: what i want is a similar command like \citep{},  Author + number in bracket: eg.  (Loh [1]) other than only number " ( [1] ) " is shown

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative path from the one proposed by locstep, is to add `natbib=true` to the `biblatex` package options, keeping `style=numeric`. Then, just cite your sources with `\citet`, which will simulate the same Author+citation label from `natbib`.